# How can I have the app send off GPS location after timer runs out while app is in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, background-process

I want to send off the users location while the app is in the background.  In the app the user can set a timer, from 1 minute to 24 hours.  I have tried to have the app run in the background and it does work for only ten minutes.  If I set a timer for longer than ten minutes, then background the app, the app does not keep running in the background for over ten minutes.  Is it possible to have the app run for longer than ten minutes?  Up to at least two hours?

Here is what I have tried:

I added this to my plist:

[image]

I added this to my `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method:

```
    __weak BADAppDelegate * weakSelf = self;
    self.backgroundTaskIdentifier =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        int timeTilDone = timerSeconds;// two hours

        self.bgTimer =
        [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:timeTilDone
                                target:weakSelf
                              selector:@selector(startTrackLocation)
                              userInfo:nil
                               repeats:NO];

        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.bgTimer
                                  forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];


        self.testTimer =
        [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:60
                                target:weakSelf
                              selector:@selector(playSilentSound)
                              userInfo:nil
                               repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.testTimer
                                  forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];


    });
```

I tried to force it to stay alive by playing a sound every minute

```
-(void)playSilentSound
{
if(self.silentSnd == nil)
{
    NSString *soundFile;
    if ((soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"halfsec" ofType:@"caf"]))
    {
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFile];
        self.silentSnd = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
        self.silentSnd.delegate = self;
        [self.silentSnd setNumberOfLoops:1];
    }
}

[self.silentSnd prepareToPlay];
[self.silentSnd play];
}
```

But that doesn't help.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is my locationManager init code:

```
    NSLog(@"StartTrackLocation");
    if(self.locationManager == nil)
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: which method do you use: didUpdateFromLocationToLocation or didUpdateToLocations ?

Comment: I use locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:

Answer (score 1):

On init set `CLLocationManager` property `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to false.
If set to true, Apple thinks that the user does not need GPS and shut down that service.

It is highly recommendable that your read line per line of the [CLLocationManager Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) at each major ios Update (next will be 7.0)

(Altough your question is not really documented)

Forget your method `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`, that is not neccessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically is set to false.  I think my question is unclear, unless I don't understand your answer corectly.  I don't want the location to be sent right when I exit the app.  I want it to be sent off after the timer ends, which works when they set it to under ten minutes, but any more, the app is killed after ten minutes.

Comment: I have understood your question. The main goal is that the app always stays alive. whenever you then send, is another question. My app always stays alive in background when locations are enabled. Please post your locationManager init code.

Comment: Ha, so I guess you were saying something similar to Rob Napier, I just didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

To keep track of location, you need to tell the system you want updates. You do that by calling `startUpdatingLocation` (to get fine-grained updates) and/or `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` (to get low-energy-cost, but less frequent, updates, ~500m changes, often usually when the user changes cell towers). It is common to use both (since `...SignificantChanges` will launch you if you're terminated, while `startUpdatingLocation` won't). You may also set a region with `startMonitoringForRegion:` and you will be alerted when the user enters or leaves it.

Beyond that, you're trying to outsmart the system with timers and the like. That will only tend to get you in trouble.

That said, your specific request is not possible in the most general case. You cannot say "I want to wake up at such-and-such-a-time." That's not a solvable problem in iOS 6. What you can say is that you're a location app and get constant updates on location. You can then, each time you are updated with a location, check whether it's time to do something. But if the user sits still for hours, and you're in the background (and particularly if you're terminated), then there is no way to be woken up.

There may be solutions for this problem in unreleased versions of iOS, but you will have to discuss that on the developers' forums.

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought of that.  Could you suggest a way of unlocking a "put" to a database when a user-set amount of time has gone by?  I guess I can find a timestamp of when the users location should be updated, then check the current time, and if its past I could let the location be sent to the database.

Comment: Exactly as you say. I'd just hold onto the information until the time has passed. You probably want to setup a timer for yourself in applicationDidFinishLaunching: (in case you're terminated and restarted).

Comment: So, if I start tracking the location with this code, it should last for over an hour or two if I don't turn off the update location right?

Comment: Don't forget that you have access to `deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable` to check for where the user was in the past (to the extent that it was known)

Comment: Once you turn on location tracking, it's forever until you stop it (provided the user allows it). With `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, the system will even restart you if you're terminated or the device reboots.